# How to Blanket Redirect all URL's to Different Domain Sub-directory no Mask

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

**.htaccess Rules**

```
Redirect 301 "/page-1/" "https://www.newdomain.com/page-1/"
Redirect 301 "/anotherpage/run/" "https://www.newdomain.com/anotherpage/run/"
Redirect 301 "/" "https://www.newdomain.com/subdirectory/"
```

**Current Results**

The first two rules which are specific pages work well. The problem is with the catch all which will carry on the URI at the destination url. Only needing for anything other than specified URI rules to 301 to the new domain sub directory.

eg.

```
https://olddomain.com/page-5/ to https://www.newdomain.com/subdirectory/
```

**Expected Results**

```
https://olddomain.com/page-1/ redirects to https://www.newdomain.com/page-1/
https://olddomain.com/anotherpage/run/ redirects to https://www.newdomain.com/anotherpage/run/
https://olddomain.com/anypage/fun/ redirects to https://www.newdomain.com/subdirectory/
```

I've tried a couple Rewrite rules with no luck. It carries the complete URI to the new domain.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.newdomain.com/subdirectory/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this rules on the top of your olddomain.com .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # custom rewrites
    RewriteRule ^page-1/$ https://www.newdomain.com/page-1/ [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^anotherpage/run/$ https://www.newdomain.com/anotherpage/run/ [R=301,L]

    # rewrite all not custom matched requests to https://www.newdomain.com/subdirectory/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.newdomain.com/subdirectory/ [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```